# How can Oracle use a Range Scan here?

Tags: oracle, index

I have a **Customer** table, with the columns "Name", "Location" and "DateMovedIn" (amongst others), which contains c. 20,000,000 rows.

On this table, I have the index **I_LOC_NAME_DATE**, such that:

```
Column          Position  Descend
Location        1         ASC
Name            2         ASC
DateMovedIn     3         ASC
```

I'm writing a query which selects the customer's who moved into their location between two dates;

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Customer 
WHERE  Customer.DateMovedIn BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
AND    Customer.Location = :location;
```

From what I've read about Oracle's use of indexes, in this situation I would expect it to use a **skip scan** (filter by Location, and then hop betwen the names and get each move in date), but it turns out it uses a **range scan**.

An `EXPLAIN` reveals the **range scan** cost to be 77, and when I apply a `index_ss` hint as follows, the cost jumps to 401,096 (yes, really).

```
SELECT /*+ index_ss(Customer I_LOC_NAME_DATE) */ * 
FROM   Customer 
WHERE  Customer.DateMovedIn BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date
AND    Customer.Location = :location;
```

Can anyone explain *how* Oracle is using a range scan in this circumstance *without* the `Name` being specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a leading column specified in condition (`Location = :location`) . From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/optimops.htm#45076) :

> The optimizer uses a range scan when it finds one or more leading columns of an index specified in conditions, such as the following:
>   col1 = :b1
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

It uses a range scan because `location` is the first field in the composite index. It's cheaper (according to its stats) to get all matching index records for that location, and it possibly then filters the index results on the date range before retrieving table data.

A skip scan would be considered if you were querying on `name` and `datemovedin`, or just on `datemovedin`.